# Parallel writing in MySQL. How to write streaming entries to 100 different tables in MySQL database using Python mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am wondering how I could write streaming data to different MySQL tables in a parallel way?

I have the following code: where the `GetStreaming()` returns a list of tuple `[(tbName,data1,data2),(tbName,data1,data2),...]` available at the time of call.

```
import mysql.connector
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
def foo(tb1,d1,d2):
   global cursor
   stmt = lambda tb1: "INSERT INTO {:} (col1,col2) VALUES (%s, %s)".format(tb1)
   cursor.execute(stmt(tb1), (d1,d2))
if __name=="__main__":
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config) 
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   for _ in range(int(1e5)):
      data = GetStreaming()
      with Pool() as p:
         p.map(foo, data)
      cnx.commit()
   cursor.close()
   cnx.close()
```

If I replace the `with Pool() as p: p.map(foo, data)` with an ordinary for loop

```
for each in data:
   foo(each)
```

The code can work. However, with the multiprocessing way, I can no longer do so. I tried multiple methods and I got errors like mysql disconnect or not picklable.

Comment: 100 tables sounds like a failure of relational database design and normalization, unless this is some kind of sharding system.

Comment: @tadman There is not much relation among the tables. The only relation is the timestamp for each row.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `format` to introduce data into your queries. This creates huge SQL injection vulnerabilities. The `execute()` command takes a tuple which can bind data values easily and without such risks.

Comment: If you have 100 tables that are largely the same, then that's not a relational design. There should be one table with a column indicating the different data partitions. Use database-level partitioning if you have performance problems. Beyond that you can use sharding, but that's usually done across multiple distinct database instances.

Comment: @tadman In term of vulnerabilities introduced by  ```format``, how can I also bind table names as well?

Comment: You can't, but normally you shouldn't. You need to explain your use case better as having N tables that are virtually identical is almost always a mistake. It's better having one table with a column that represents whatever that table name or ID is, like `a, col1, col2` where `a` is some kind of indexed value.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the introduction of database-level partitioning as well as sharding. In terms of the use case, I want to store the real time temperature as well as humidity in each city. so that at each row there would be a timestamp, temperature and humidity. Right now I have one table for one city. Would that be a little cumbersome to put them in a big table?

Comment: "Table per city" is a failure of relational database design. What you want is one table with a `city_id` column that's indexed. If you ever end up with too many samples in here, use [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/8.0/en/partitioning-types.html), though you'll only need that once you hit hundreds of millions to billions of records on a table with a row this compact.

Comment: @tadman Thank you very much for the incisive comments on my design issue. Definitely my next step is to look up to the partitioning and learn to appreciate the relational database design.

Comment: `PARTITIONing` is unlikely to be of any benefit, either.

Comment: Another tip for this type of dataset:  Have `city` be the first column in a multi-column `PRIMARY KEY`.  (This assumes that you will commonly do `SELECT ... WHERE city = '...'`.)

Comment: @RickJames May I ask why ```PARTITIONING``` is unlikely to be of any benefit? Are you suggesting that loading data would become slow even if I partition the big table by ```city``` using the SQL's PARTITION?

Comment: @Ethanabc - With rare exceptions, the load speed would be about the same between partitioned and non-partitioned.  In a decade of searching, I have found only a few uses for partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the partitioning heads-up as well as the tip on ```city``` column location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each "parallel" insertion process needs its own connector and cursor. You can't share them across any sort of thread.

You can use [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html) to make faster the allocation and release of connections.

There's no magic in MySQL (or any DBMS costing less than the GDP of a small country) that lets it scale up to handle large scale data insertion on ~100 connections simultaneously. Paradoxically, more connections can have lower throughput than fewer connections, because of contention between them. You may want to rethink your system architecture so you can make it work OK with a few connections.

In other words: **fewer bigger tables perform much better than many small tables.**

Finally, read about ways of speeding up bulk inserts.  For example this sort of multirow insert

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (
  (1,2),
  (3,4),
  (5,6) );
```

will run almost three times faster than three consecutive inserts

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (5,6);
```

unless you do this:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (5,6);
COMMIT;
```

because the hard work of insertion happens at COMMIT time. For many real-world use cases, my experience says chunks of about 100 rows work pretty well.

And the gold standard for insertion speed is [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). For that to work you need your data in csv or csv-like files, though.

Comment: A "multi-insert" can be ridiculously fast, as can be `LOAD DATA INFILE`. A prepared statement for a particular table can also be recycled endlessly.

Comment: "the hard work of insertion happens at COMMIT time".   Do you mean that the time of    ```COMMIT``` is so long that the difference of insert one by one or insert in bulk is neglectable?

How about this ```START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (
  (1,2),
  (3,4),
  (5,6) );
COMMIT;```    Is it the same speed as ```START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (5,6);
COMMIT;```?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. For reasonably short rows, in my experience, chunks of 100 rows or so work pretty well.  And @tadman's `LOAD DATA INFILE` suggestion is also worth considering.

Comment: In my experience, a batch `INSERT` of 100 rows is 10 times as fast as 100 single-row inserts.